# See user id in linux journalctl

Tags: linux, logging

I use `journalctl -f` to see the logs written by the processes, but it does not print the user who initiated the process writing to syslog.
Is there any option we can provide to journalctl in order to print the user id?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `journalctl -o verbose` you will see the complete log record for each entry, which will look something like:

```
Fri 2019-08-02 20:02:11.307673 EDT [s=e328b42f9ccd4ef28cc946dba525b34c;i=12377a1;b=299ec3a7a9e545f3ab77225c045aee0c;m=7a7d1960ef;t=58f2b2fc43900;x=ceff52112a8146ae]
    _TRANSPORT=journal
    _UID=1000
    _GID=1000
    _CAP_EFFECTIVE=0
    _AUDIT_LOGINUID=1000
    _SYSTEMD_OWNER_UID=1000
    _SYSTEMD_SLICE=user-1000.slice
    _SYSTEMD_USER_SLICE=-.slice
    _BOOT_ID=299ec3a7a9e545f3ab77225c045aee0c
    _MACHINE_ID=39332780e5924d6ba0bdf775223941f6
    _HOSTNAME=madhatter
    PRIORITY=6
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=3
    CODE_FILE=../src/core/job.c
    CODE_LINE=594
    CODE_FUNC=job_log_begin_status_message
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=systemd
    MESSAGE=Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
    JOB_ID=1446
    JOB_TYPE=start
    USER_UNIT=gnome-terminal-server.service
    USER_INVOCATION_ID=188bcf32f532490c8ce5ec486895f9d0
    MESSAGE_ID=7d4958e842da4a758f6c1cdc7b36dcc5
    _PID=3329
    _COMM=systemd
    _EXE=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
    _CMDLINE=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
    _AUDIT_SESSION=3
    _SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/init.scope
    _SYSTEMD_UNIT=user@1000.service
    _SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT=init.scope
    _SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID=5537b4a00b5946ce9f3b2b664c3d10e8
    _SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=1564790531307673
```

Take a look at `man journalctl` for more information. E.g., there is a `-o json` if you want to programtically process log lines in some fashion.